# If else no statistics arcpy

Tags: arcpy, if-else

I need to run my code through a lot of rasters that i've downloaded with "Download Raster" function, but some rasters have no information, so my script fails. I wonder if there's any way to use an if/else statement to solve my problem, in other words, if there's statsitics in the image, run the code, else, ignore the raster and select the next one.

I tried this, but it's not working...

for tiff in rasters:

```
    NodataResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (tiff, "ANYNODATA", "")
    Nodata = NodataResult.getOutput


    if Nodata = 1

        CalculateStatistics_management (tiff)

    else

        arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tiff, "Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\temp_rast1.tif", "", "", "3")
        arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tiff, "Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\temp_rast2.tif", "", "", "4")
```

Comment: Yes you can use if/else logic with some python scripting.

Comment: Do you have any ideia about how can i write that? I'm new in python scripting

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the help file, look [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm), they show you code or similar approaches in modelbuilder.

Comment: You're not using Python `if` syntax (missing colons) and you're using the assignment operator instead of equivalence.

Comment: What you are looking for is try: and except: though if and else may work if you correct your syntax errors as @Vince has pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

A simple if statement by your example (note the double "==" for comparison), goes like:

```
if NoData == 1:
   #do something here
else:
   #do something different here
```

You can find more detailed examples on the [web](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html). [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=comparisons) you can learn abit more about comparing values to build your statement.